# Output values from a 2D array, (array[j][i]), into Excel to form a table with i columns and j rows

Tags: c, arrays, excel

I have written a program that models heat flux through a 1D solid. It produces a value for the flux at all distances, x and then increments the time and repeats. My problem now is that I would like to write the results to Excel in a format that produces a basic table with the variation in distance running horizontally and the variation in time running vertically.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

float fluxfunction(int x,int t)
{
    int n, L=10, q1=2, k = 5;
    float flux1=0, pi = 3.141592, exp = 2.718281;

    for(n=1;n<=1000;n++)
            {
                flux1+=q1*(2/(pi*n))*(cos(n*pi)-1)*(sin((n*pi*(x+L))/(2*L)))*pow(exp,-(k*t*(n*n*pi*pi)/(4*L*L)));
            }
            flux1+=q1;

    return flux1;
}


int main()
{
    int i, j, L=10,tmax=30;
    float f, results [tmax+1][L+1];
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("fouriertest.csv", "w");

    for(j=0;j<=tmax;j++)
    {
        for(i=0;i<=L;i++)
        {
            results [j][i]=fluxfunction(i,j);
            if (i==L)
            {
                fprintf(fp, "%f\n",results [j][i]);
            }
            else
            {
                fprintf(fp, "%f",results [j][i]);
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is what I've got so far, but unfortunately, where I try write the values for increasing `i` along a column, there is no cell separation. Shown by the picture here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbN5y.png

Comment: The "C" in "CSV" stands for *comma* separated values. You don't have any separator at all.

Comment: Thanks, what do you mean "I don't have any separator at all."? What will a separator do? How to I get one?

Comment: Oh thanks, I've got it now. Turns out I just needed a comma after the %f. Great thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

you have to separate field using `';'` coma character; your main function should be like this:

```
int main()
{
    int i, j, L=10,tmax=30;
    float f, results [tmax+1][L+1];
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("fouriertest.csv", "w");

    for(j=0;j<=tmax;j++)
    {
        for(i=0;i<=L;i++)
        {
            results [j][i]=fluxfunction(i,j);
            fprintf(fp, "%f%c",results [j][i],(i==L)?'\n':';');

        }
    }
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i don't see any reason that let you declare the table results!!. unless you need it somewhere else.